# How do you reference another class from a controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to use a service class inside of my controller. I cannot figure out how to reference other classes in rails. Here is my `users_controller`, located under `app/controllers/api/v1`:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :initialize_user_service

  def create
    @service.create
    render json: CustomResponse.new(
      {
        user: @service.user,
      }
    )
  end

  def initialize_user_service
    @service = Services::UserService.new(user_params)
  end

  def user_params
    params.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

I am attempting to reference this `users_service.rb` class located in `app/services/users_service.rb`:

```
class Services::UserService
  attr_reader :session, :user

  def initialize(params)
    # @user_id = params[:id]
    @params = params
  end

  def create
    user = User.create(@params)
    if user.save
      return user
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

But I get the following error in the console:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController::Services):
```

Does anyone know what I can do to access this class? I cannot find a solution. I imagine it may have something to do with my `config/application.rb` file, but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

I think, problem is with your filename: `app/services/users_service.rb`. Since your class name is `UserService`, it should rather be: `app/services/user_service.rb` (`user_service` instead of `users_service`).

`UserService` will expect to load the class from a file called as `user_service.rb` in autoload path.

Define your service as following:
Filename: `app/services/user_service.rb`.
Definition:

```
module Services
  class UserService
    attr_reader :session, :user

    def initialize(params)
      # @user_id = params[:id]
      @params = params
    end

    def create
      user = User.create(@params)
      if user.save
        return user
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`Services::UserService.new(user_params)` should work as intended.

Comment: Wow, the 6th answer is the first one _almost_ correct :) Please also advise to triple-check that `services` directory is included to the list of autoloaded paths.

Comment: :) I avoided writing it since all sub-directories in `app/` are autoloaded by default (dont' remember the behavior of < Rails 4). Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, indeed. I missed that it’s `app/services`, not just `services`. Anyway, I have it upvoted already.

Comment: I tried adding the module and it still wouldn't work. If I remove all modules/namespaces and just reference UserService then it works. But I really don't want to do this. I want to use namespaces. It seems that it makes the code much more organized and maintainable.

Comment: I did update the file name to `user_service.rb` as well

Comment: are you still creating the class by `class Services::UserService` ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `::Services::UserService.new(user_params)`, Ruby assume you declare this class in the Api::V1 module, `::` means the root module. Or you can declare your service like this:

`class Api::V1::Services::UserService
 end`

Comment: Wrong. If `UserService` name was corresponding the file name and the path was included into auto-loaded path (or the file was required explicitly,) ruby constant would be successfully resolved.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks, but `UserService` is not corresponding the file name in auto-loaded path. My answer is right for the issue.

Comment: Different file name would prevent autoloading at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of defined namespace. It will work by simply putting your service class directly in service directory is enough. Check for `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` for a basic idea of which folders are included. Even if you are using namespace then you need to update for the autoload path with it.
something like below

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/your_xyz_path )
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to define namespace, just write it with your service name, like following

```
class UserService

  attr_reader :session, :user

  def initialize(params)
    # @user_id = params[:id]
    @params = params
  end

  def create
     user = User.create(@params)
       if user.save
            return user
       else
            false
       end
  end

end
```

And call it using `UserService.new(params)`
And for production mode define it in `application.rb` file to autoload the service like following
`config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services')]`

Comment: Sounds like “use global variables everywhere!“ The OP clearly stated they want to use a namespace/fq-name. The advice “just don’t use namespaces” looks as an off-topic to me.

Comment: @mudasobwa, he is just asking for what is the error for "Api::V1::UsersController::Services", And I didn't suggest do not use namespace, I just give the solution of error.
And you can put your own opinion, please don't down vote the answer as per your personal opinion.

Comment: Please don’t tell me what I am to do. This answer is of very low quality, it does not explain what the real issue is and, after all, it does not solve the issue. Also, “I didn't suggest do not use namespace” is a lie, you might want to re-read the very first sentence of your answer.

Comment: You also do not need to tell me, "No need to define namespace", I give the solution as per error, I didn't mean that you cant use namespace.

Comment: You gave the _wrong solution_. Read the answer by @kiddorails for the correct one.

Comment: I dont want t say anything to you man.
You just come and downvote all the answer.

Comment: I have downvoted all the incorrect answers, yes. And I upvoted the correct one. That’s how voting on SO works.

Answer (score -2):

Defining service like this is enough. There's no need namespace for this:

```
class UserService
end

# using
@service = UserService.new(user_params)
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated they want to use a namespace. The advice “just don’t use namespaces” is plain wrong.

Comment: Yeah it works without namespaces. But I would much prefer to use them.

Answer (score -2):

The code under app directory is autoloaded and all the directories too. So there should be no namespace in your service class.

```
class UserService
end
```

and this should work in any controller or model/class like

```
user_service = UserService.new
```

Comment: “there should be no namespace”—plain wrong. Everybody has a right to use namespaces.

Comment: In service class, if using namespace then the directory structure should be also similar to the namespace.

Eg:-

`module Services
  class UserService
  end
end`

Here, directory structure should be app/services/services/user_service.rb

Comment: This last comment was really helpful. Thanks!